# react-native audio recorder not stopping

Tags: react-native

My record stop button isnt working when I'm clicking on the record start then the record stop button getting an error that says "Println needs a message". What do I need to change?

Also my state component for the timer also isnt updating any suggestion why?
The timer should change when i click the start record button and then clear out when i say stop

```
`import AudioRecorderPlayer, {
    AVEncoderAudioQualityIOSType,
    AVEncodingOption,
    AudioEncoderAndroidType,
    AudioSet,
    AudioSourceAndroidType,
} from 'react-native-audio-recorder-player'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Button, Text } from 'react-native'
import { Header, Divider } from 'react-native-elements'
class Record extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoggingIn: false,
            recordSecs: 0,
            recordTime: '00:00:00',
            currentPositionSec: 0,
            currentDurationSec: 0,
            playTime: '00:00:00',
            duration: '00:00:00',
        };
        this.audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();
        this.audioRecorderPlayer.setSubscriptionDuration(0.09); // optional. Default is 0.1
    }

    onStartRecord = async () => {
        const path = 'hello.m4a';
        const audioSet = {
            AudioEncoderAndroid: AudioEncoderAndroidType.AAC,
            AudioSourceAndroid: AudioSourceAndroidType.MIC,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKeyIOS: AVEncoderAudioQualityIOSType.high,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKeyIOS: 2,
            AVFormatIDKeyIOS: AVEncodingOption.aac,
        };
        console.log('audioSet', audioSet);
        const uri = await this.audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder(path, audioSet);
        this.audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener((e) => {
            this.setState({
                recordSecs: e.current_position,
                recordTime: this.audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(
                    Math.floor(e.current_position),
                ),
            });
        });
        console.log(`uri: ${uri}`);
    };


    onStopRecord = async () => {
        const result = await this.audioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder();
        this.audioRecorderPlayer.removeRecordBackListener();
        this.setState({
            recordSecs: 0,
        });
        console.log(result);
    };

    onStartPlay = async (e) => {
        console.log('onStartPlay');
        const path = 'sdcard/hello.m4a'
        const msg = await this.audioRecorderPlayer.startPlayer(path);
        this.audioRecorderPlayer.setVolume(1.0);
        console.log(msg);
        this.audioRecorderPlayer.addPlayBackListener((e) => {
            if (e.current_position === e.duration) {
                console.log('finished');
                this.audioRecorderPlayer.stopPlayer();
            }
            this.setState({
                currentPositionSec: e.current_position,
                currentDurationSec: e.duration,
                playTime: this.audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(
                    Math.floor(e.current_position),
                ),
                duration: this.audioRecorderPlayer.mmssss(Math.floor(e.duration)),
            });
        });
    };

    onPausePlay = async (e) => {
        await this.audioRecorderPlayer.pausePlayer();
    };


    onStopPlay = async (e) => {
        console.log('onStopPlay');
        this.audioRecorderPlayer.stopPlayer();
        this.audioRecorderPlayer.removePlayBackListener();
    };

    render() {
        return (<View>
            <Header>InstaPlayer</Header>
            <Text>{this.state.recordTime}</Text>
            <Button title="Record" onPress={() => this.onStartRecord()} />
            <Button title="Stop"
                onPress={() => this.onStopRecord()}
            />
            <Text>{this.state.playTime} / {this.state.duration}</Text>
            <Button title="PLAY" onPress={() => this.onStartPlay()} />
            <Button
                title="Pause"
                onPress={() => this.onPausePlay()}
            />
            <Button
                title="Stop"
                onPress={() => this.onStopPlay()}
            />
        </View>)
    }
}

export default Record`
```

Comment: Getting this same error but only on certain versions of android. Were you able to find a fix?

Comment: import SoundRecorder from 'react-native-sound-recorder';

I've used this package as a workaround with the file system. So the stop function calls this SoundRecorder.stop() method. Hope this helps!!! Feel free to reach me here

Comment: Try wrapping the audioRecorderPlayer.stopPlayer() in a try/catch. If I remember right, that is what fixed it for me. The stopPlayer() method was throwing an error and it wasn't handled correctly. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience this error seems to be happening when the recorder is not stopped properly in the previous run. If the recorder is stopped properly, this error doesn't occur for me.